# Adding fields on the fly

Tags: atk4

I have a form with a table source, the form has a few fields (product, quantity)

I'm thinking to add a button that allows me to add another "line" with product, quantity.... and so on, because I don't know how many items I need to add.

Which is the best approach ?

maybe removing the StaticSource('') and implementing on the submit the inserts ?

Thanks
Alejandro

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you're adding a button, which inserts record into table and reloads the table?

Comment: romas, I want to add a button that adds more fields to the form, and when I click de "Submit" button, the $f->update(); adds all the fields to a table

Comment: You can add fields dynamically, on button click, collect the information into a hidden field and submit. Agile Toolkit will not look into POST of undefined fields, but you can do it old-school way and look into POST yourself. You can also do $form->js_widget=false to disable AJAX submission.

Comment: Romans thanks, I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class page_yourpage extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->add("CRUD")->setModel("Product");
    }

}

class Model_Product extends Model_Table {
    $entity_code = "yourtable";
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField("product_id")->refModel("Model_Product");
        $this->addField("quantity");
    }

}
```

that's it. (did not test in browser);